# OOP: method returning new instance, what should child return?

Tags: typescript, oop

I'm using typescript. I have a class with a method that returns a new instance of the class.

```
class A {
  map (args) {
    return new A(/* change something*/);
  }
}
```

And I subclass `A`.

```
class B extends A {
}
```

My question is: is there a best practice in OOP that says that the `map` function in `B` should return a `B`? Or is it only the developer's choice to return `A` or `B` (i.e. with method overwrite).

Comment: Ideally (but I don't know <strike>enough</strike> any TypeScript to suggest how to implement this), `map` wouldn't hard-code `A`, but return in instance of whatever class invoked `map`. (As an analogy in Python, you would define as a class method `def map(cls): return cls(...)` instead of `def map(cls): return A(...)`.)

Comment: For consistency, you would not expect `B`.map to return `A`.

Comment: @chepner - For built-in classes like Array, you'll be glad to know that's exactly what JavaScript (and thus TypeScript) does. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single best practice here. It depends on what `map` does and the semantics you want it to have.

One data point to consider specifically in regard to the operation popularly called `map`, such as the one on Array (and to `filter`, `slice`, and such): By default, the implementation in Array would return `B` (without any special work from you). But an implementation could override that default behavior if it made more sense to return `A` instead.

Example using Array's default behavior (in JavaScript, but it works the same in TypeScript):

```js
class B extends Array {
}
const b1 = new B("a", "b", "c");
const b2 = b1.map(entry => entry.toUpperCase());
console.log(b2 instanceof Array); // true
console.log(b2 instanceof B);     // true
```

Example overriding Array's default behavior (again, in JS):

```js
class B extends Array {
    static get [Symbol.species]() {
        return Array;
    }
}
const b1 = new B("a", "b", "c");
const b2 = b1.map(entry => entry.toUpperCase());
console.log(b2 instanceof Array); // true
console.log(b2 instanceof B);     // false
```

For more on how that works: [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species)

`Promise` does the same thing (and `Map` and `Set`) for operations that result in a new promise (or map or set), so you could argue there's some standard library support for the idea of returning `B` from similar operations.

> Or is it only the developer's choice to return A or B (i.e. with method overwrite).

Correct.